# Difference between Refresh and Navigate function in browser control?

Tags: c#, browser, refresh, webbrowser-control

Yesterday I came across one of the sites that uses to display the "Views"(i.e.the no of persons visited the page).When I clicked the refresh button the count started increasing.

Then I wrote this small application to increase the view count.

```
 browser = new WebBrowser();
 for (int index = 0; index < 250000; index++)
 {
   {
     browser.Navigate("url");
     System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
   }
 }
```

I reported the bug and they have rectified it.Now even if I press the F5 button the view count won't increase.But when I run the above program the count starts increasing..

Can somebody explain me the difference between Navigate function and Refresh(F5)?

Comment: Can somebody briefly explain what's happening in the code behind?

Comment: From what I could see, its just that refresh doesn't call some events, very interesting question though

Comment: @Sayse Can u explain what difference does it make while requesting for web page?

Comment: I'm sorry but I've been looking and not found anything regarding that, it may depend on the website, but at a guess I'd say websites rely on these events to say when a new user has navigated to the website (the MSDN for these events doesn't go into great detail)

Comment: @Sayse Thanks!! I too am looking for the reasons for this behaviour..

Comment: [This link supports my theory loosely](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080126170857AAShgrb)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Navigate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/40x214wa.aspx)

> Loads the document at the specified Uniform Resource Locator (URL) into the WebBrowser control, **replacing the previous document**.

[Refresh](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txewax99.aspx)

> **Reloads the document** currently displayed in the WebBrowser control.
>
> A document refresh simply reloads the current page, so the Navigating, Navigated, and DocumentCompleted events do not occur when you call the Refresh method.

Note: Links are for webbrowser control but I presume their information is valid