# Selenium driver.Url vs. driver.Navigate().GoToUrl()

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Which is the preferred method to open a Url (and are there any differences behind the scenes between):

```
driver.Url = "http://example.com";
```

or

```
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://example.com");
```

Also, if the driver is already pointing at the same page, will setting the Url a second time cause the page to refresh?

i.e.

```
...
driver.Url = "http://example.com";
driver.Url = "http://example.com"; //does this reload the page?
...
```

FWIW I'm using the Chrome driver chromedriver.exe, but it doesn't appear to be a managed assembly (I tried opening it with ILSpy but no luck).

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Selenium is an open source framework, so please have a look at the source code [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/tree/master/dotnet/src/webdriver/Remote).

`GoToUrl()` is defined in [RemoteNavigator.cs](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/dotnet/src/webdriver/Remote/RemoteNavigator.cs):

```
/// <summary>
/// Navigate to a url for your test
/// </summary>
/// <param name="url">String of where you want the browser to go to</param>
public void GoToUrl(string url)
{
    this.driver.Url = url;
}

/// <summary>
/// Navigate to a url for your test
/// </summary>
/// <param name="url">Uri object of where you want the browser to go to</param>
public void GoToUrl(Uri url)
{
    if (url == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("url", "URL cannot be null.");
    }

    this.driver.Url = url.ToString();
}
```

So basically `driver.Navigate().GoToUrl();` sets `driver.Url` under the hood and I don't see a difference there.

However, `driver.Navigate().GoToUrl()` is more flexible, which allows sending either `string` or `Uri` as parameter types, while only string is allowed when setting through `driver.Url`.

---

To your second question, the source code shows that `driver.Navigate().Refresh()` asks browsers to refresh, while `driver.Url` tells browsers to navigate. So these two are fundamentally different. For more details, please see [Difference between Refresh and Navigate function in browser control?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17963824/1177636)

If you want to refresh the page, please use `driver.Navigate().Refresh();`

`Refresh()` is defined in [RemoteNavigator.cs](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/dotnet/src/webdriver/Remote/RemoteNavigator.cs):

```
/// <summary>
/// Refresh the browser
/// </summary>
public void Refresh()
{
    // driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
    this.driver.InternalExecute(DriverCommand.Refresh, null);
}
```

`driver.Url` is defined in [RemoteWebDriver.cs](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/dotnet/src/webdriver/Remote/RemoteWebDriver.cs):

```
public string Url
{
    ...

    set
    {
        ...

        try
        {
            this.Execute(DriverCommand.Get, parameters);
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Looking at the source code you provided it looks like the answer to my second question is yes - the code always tells the driver to reload the page, even if the Url hasn't changed.

Comment: @steve: Yeah, it depends on how you define words "reload" and "refresh". ;)

Comment: `driver.Navigate().GoToUrl()` only set operation .But `driver.Url` set and get current URL

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Yi Zeng's answer, the difference between reloading and refreshing has to do with the driver information about the page. If we re-assign **driver.Url = url** again, the memory will host this overridden string value one more time —regardless of being the same. While refreshing has to do with displaying updated data.